# AJAX JQuery mobile collapsible acting as if in separate collapsible sets

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-collapsible

```
if(x.length > 0){
    $("#txtHint").append('<div data-role="collapsible-set" id="collapsible-set"></div>');
    for(i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
        var collapsible = '<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true" data-theme="none">Content</div>';
                    $("[data-role=collapsible-set]").append($(collapsible).collapsible()).trigger("create");
    } 
}
```

It appends the collapsible divs ok, but they display as if they are in separate sets even though they are not.

This gives a clearer picture of what's happening visually: http://jsfiddle.net/gNJn8/

Comment: use `.collapsibleset()` as follows `$("[data-role=collapsible-set]").append(collapsible).collapsibleset().trigger("create");`

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery mobile cannot refresh the collapsibleset](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17378836/jquery-mobile-cannot-refresh-the-collapsibleset)